# How to combine items in List<string> to make new items efficiently

Tags: c#, .net

I have a case where I have the name of an object, and a bunch of file names. I need to match the correct file name with the object. The file name can contain numbers and words, separated by either hyphen(-) or underscore(_). I have no control of either file name or object name. For example:

```
10-11-12_001_002_003_13001_13002_this_is_an_example.svg
```

The object name in this case is just a string, representing an number

```
10001
```

I need to return true or false if the file name is a match for the object name. The different segments of the file name can match on their own, or any combination of two segments. In the example above, it should be true for the following cases (not every true case, just examples):

```
10001
10002
10003
11001
11002
11003
12001
12002
12003
13001
13002
```

And, we should return false for this case (among others):

```
13003
```

What I've come up with so far is this:

```
public bool IsMatch(string filename, string objectname)
{
    var namesegments = GetNameSegments(filename);
    var match = namesegments.Contains(objectname);
    return match;
}

public static List<string> GetNameSegments(string filename)
{
    var segments = filename.Split('_', '-').ToList();

    var newSegments = new List<string>();
    foreach (var segment in segments)
    {
        foreach (var segment2 in segments)
        {
            if (segment == segment2)
                continue;

            var newToken = segment + segment2;
            newSegments.Add(newToken);
        }
    }

    return segments.Concat(newSegments).ToList();
}
```

One or two segments combined can make a match, and that is enought. Three or more segments combined should not be considered.

This does work so far, but is there a better way to do it, perhaps without nesting foreach loops?

Comment: This question might be better suited for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Any restrictions on these segments? Is object name is always 5 digit number? Are segments in string always 2,3 or 5 digit numbers?

Comment: @mjwills Because 10 and 001 both exist as separate segments. Combine them and you get 10001

Comment: @Evk Unfortunately no, no such restrictions. Object name could contain letters or numbers, and lenght is not restricted in any way. Same with tokens in string.

Comment: Could you take a step back and explain why you need to do this? What do the segments in the file name represent? Why are you concatenating them? _Just in case this is a XY Problem - https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem ._

Comment: And match is possible with any number of segments? Because your current solution only works when 1 or 2 segments combined create a match. What if name is "10-11-12" and object id is "101112"?

Comment: @mjwills The first one, yes. The other two no, since that requires three segments combined.

Comment: @Evk 1 or 2 segments combined can make a match yes, but not 3 or more.

Comment: @mjwills Yes and yes.

Comment: Reverse match is also valid? means `1110` out of `10-11`?

Comment: @Bharadwaj Yes, the order of the segments doesn't matter.

Comment: I note that you restricted the problem to *unique* segments. What happens if there are two identical segments?  Like `10-10-12-...`  Or does this never happen?

Comment: @EricLippert All the examples I had was unique segments, but I've checked with the customer and it is possible but unlikely that identical segments appear. I've edited the question and removed the unique part

Comment: Since this is about code review and not about solving any problem I returned the favor and downvoted the question as well as all answers. I also vote to close it as off-topic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Efficiency is very much dependent on the business problem that you're attempting to solve. Without knowing the full context/usage it's difficult to define the most efficient solution. What works for one situation won't always work for others.

I would always advocate to write working code and then solve any performance issues later down the line (or throw more tin at the problem as it's usually cheaper!) If you're having *specific* performance issues then please do tell us more...

I'm going to go out on a limb here and say (hope) that you're only going to be matching the filename against the object name once per execution. If that's the case I reckon this approach will be just about the fastest. In a circumstance where you're matching a single filename against multiple object names then the obvious choice is to build up an index of sorts and match against that as you were already doing, although I'd consider different types of collection depending on your expected execution/usage.

```
public static bool IsMatch(string filename, string objectName)
{
    var segments = filename.Split('-', '_');

    for (int i = 0; i < segments.Length; i++)
    {
        if (string.Equals(segments[i], objectName)) return true;

        for (int ii = 0; ii < segments.Length; ii++)
        {
            if (ii == i) continue;
            if (string.Equals($"{segments[i]}{segments[ii]}", objectName)) return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: @spersson I think it can be about 2 times faster without the Split and few other tweaks, but not worth the trouble. I would recommend `.Length` because `System.Linq.Enumerable.Count()` does a bunch of extra unnecessary stuff https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,41ef9e39e54d0d0b

Comment: This solution does not meet the (bizarre) requirement of the original poster that the two segments be unique; according to that restriction, if the query string is `11` and the segments are `1-1` then that should return false, but your solution returns true. I suspect though that the requirement is misstated, and your solution is the correct one.

Comment: Stylistically, can you say why you used `string.Equals` and `string.Concat` rather than the more idiomatic `==` and `+` ? It's an interesting choice and I'm curious as to your thought process here.

Comment: @EricLippert I used `string.Equals` so as to allow the `StringComparison` type to be defined if required (as filenames are generally considered to be case insensitive, this might be useful although we can't be sure as we don't have all the facts), as for `string.Concat`, that was a bit of a brain fart methinks. I'm going to change it.

Answer (score 7):

First: don't change debugged, working, sufficiently efficient code for no reason. Your solution looks good.

However, we can make some improvements to your solution.

```
public static List<string> GetNameSegments(string filename)
```

Making the output a list puts restrictions on the implementation that are not required by the caller. It should be `IEnumerable<String>`.  Particularly since the caller in this case only cares about the first match.

```
var segments = filename.Split('_', '-').ToList();
```

Why `ToList`? A list is array-backed. You've already got an array in hand. Just use the array.

Since there is no longer a need to build up a list, we can transform your two-loop solution into an iterator block:

```
public static IEnumerable<string> GetNameSegments(string filename)
{
  var segments = filename.Split('_', '-');
  foreach (var segment in segments)
    yield return segment;
  foreach (var s1 in segments)
    foreach (var s2 in segments)
      if (s1 != s2)
        yield return s1 + s2; 
}
```

Much nicer.  Alternatively we could notice that this has the structure of a query and simply return the query:

```
public static IEnumerable<string> GetNameSegments(string filename)
{
  var q1= filename.Split('_', '-');
  var q2 = from s1 in q1
           from s2 in q1
           where s1 != s2
           select s1 + s2;
  return q1.Concat(q2);
}
```

Again, much nicer in this form.

Now let's talk about efficiency. As is often the case, we can achieve greater efficiency at a cost of increased complication. **This code looks like it should be plenty fast enough**. Your example has nine segments. Let's suppose that nine or ten is typical. Our solutions thus far consider the ten or so singletons first, and then the hundred or so combinations. That's nothing; this code is probably fine.  But what if we had *thousands* of segments and were considering *millions* of possibilities?

In that case we should restructure the algorithm. One possibility would be this general solution:

```
public bool IsMatch(HashSet<string> segments, string name)
{
  if (segments.Contains(name))
    return true;
  var q = from s1 in segments
          where name.StartsWith(s1)
          let s2 = name.Substring(s1.Length)
          where s1 != s2
          where segments.Contains(s2)
          select 1; // Dummy. All we care about is if there is one.
  return q.Any();
}
```

Your original solution is quadratic in the number of segments. This one is linear; we rely on the constant order contains operation. (This assumes of course that string operations are constant time because strings are short. If that's not true then we have a whole other kettle of fish to fry.)

How else could we extract wins in the asymptotic case?

- If we *happened* to have the property that the collection was not a hash set but rather a sorted list then we could do even better; we could binary search the list to find the start and end of the range of possible prefix matches, and then pour the list into a hashset to do the suffix matches. That's still linear, but could have a smaller constant factor.
- If we happened to know that the target string was small compared to the number of segments, we could attack the problem from the other end.  **Generate all possible combinations of partitions of the target string and check if both halves are in the segment set**.  The problem with this solution is that it is quadratic in memory usage in the size of the string.  So what we'd want to do there is *construct a special hash on character sequences* and use that to populate the hash table, rather than the standard string hash.  I'm sure you can see how the solution would go from there; I shan't spell out the details.

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to use the [`MoreLINQ`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/morelinq/) NuGet package then this may be worth considering:

```
public static HashSet<string> GetNameSegments(string filename)
{
    var segments = filename.Split(new char[] {'_', '-'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).ToList();

    var matches = segments
        .Cartesian(segments, (x, y) => x == y ? null : x + y)
        .Where(z => z != null)
        .Concat(segments);
    return new HashSet<string>(matches);
}
```

`StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries` handles adjacent separators (e.g. --). `Cartesian` is roughly equivalent to your existing nested for loops. The `Where` is to remove null entries (i.e. if `x == y`). `Concat` is the same as your existing `Concat`. The use of `HashSet` allows for your `Contains` calls (in `IsMatch`) to be faster.

Comment: Of course elements of segments will all be non-null, and therefore their concatenations will be as well. A fun fact about string concatenations is that string concat *never* produces null, *even when all the operands are null*. It produces an empty string in that case.

Comment: @EricLippert That is true, but that isn't exactly why I added it there. In my `Cartesian` call I am explicitly generating `null` due to my `x == y` check. This is to ensure that for `10-11-12_001_002_003_13001_13002_this_is_an_example.svg` I don't generate `1010` or `003003` as potential values, for example.

Comment: Right, I understand that. I just think it is an interesting fact that *even if some of the values in the set were null references*, your algorithm would still work correctly. You can *always* use null as a marker for "this is NOT the result of a concatenation".

Comment: I assume the downvoter was t3chb0t, per his comment on the question: "Since this is about code review and not about solving any problem I returned the favor and downvoted the question as well as all answers. I also vote to close it as off-topic."

Comment: @Brian yeah, typical SO double-standards. When I once accidentaly did a code review here I got like 5 downvotes. That's why I don't understand why this question is still open and that's why all answers deserve to be downvoted and the question itself closed because there is no doubt it's off-topic and you know that too.

Comment: As this discussion is taking away from the answer, I responded further [in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161452/codereview-a-47813719-18192).